VS Code Golang extension is not working with Docker Container [Failed to find the "go" binary in either GOROOT() or PATH(...]
The structure:

VS Code is running on my local machine.
The actual project/code is on my local machine.
Golang runtime is in a Docker container.

services:
  project1:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/srv/www


I am bind mounting the project folder into the container and execute it there. It works.

The problem:
When I install Go extension it fires the Failed to find the "go" binary in either GOROOT() or PATH(... error.
The problem is because the extension cannot find Go runtime on the local machine (where the VS Code itself actually running).
Any ideas to make this structure work?

I can make the extension working when I directly attach VS Code to the container using Dev Containers extension. But wonder if there are any other options.

Install Go on your local machine, where the extension is running? See “Go for Visual Studio Code” and “Getting started with VS Code Go”.

@eik, Evils are constantly monitoring my local machine to see if I install Go or not. If they see I have Go installed on my local machine, it's game over. GG!

Use another machine then. Or a Dev Container, like you said. The requirements for an local Go installation are pretty clearly stated.

I don't get why am I getting a Go installation guide while I am asking something completely different? If my specific structure has a way for what I am asking about, give an answer (please), if not, just say no. I am not looking for how to install Go properly.

I didn't gave you a Go installation guide but documentation that the extension requires a Go installation. You'll need the Go language server gopls installed by the extension, which needs a local Go installation. I really wonder what the problem is in just doing that.

Only the last comment is related to my question. When someone asks a specific question, it does not matter if they are right or wrong. It is better to answer only what they are asking if you have the information. Looking for why they are doing it that way just takes you off-topic. In this case, the reason is simply that I don't have the necessary permissions to install anything on the local machine. I only have access to the Docker container here.

@eik, I read this conversation again after a while, and it seems I am gone a bit rude. I don't like it. Sorry for that :)

No problem. I wonder why you don't have permissions to install binaries into your home directory without administrator privileges, it seems nearly impossible to develop under that circumstances.

It is not a usual dev env. We just sometimes connect to containers directly to edit some code (for testing purposes or checking something else) and it is not that efficient when you don't have the extension. Needed it just for that.

Yeah. In any case you need a language server running on the extension host and gopls needs Go, so you need either a local Go installation or Dev Containers or some other remote execution. Everything else is probably more work then installing Go locally, which is pretty easy.

I do something similar. VSCode and source code on my computer and all the dev tools in a container. There is a VSCode extension Dev Containers that makes working with containers easier.
With the associated devcontainer.json file for the extension you can add the following to use the VSCode go extension in the container, no need for it on your machine.
    ...
    "customizations": {
      "vscode": {
        "extensions": [
          "ms-vscode.go"
        ]
      }
    }
    ...

There is a related video here for reference Get Started with Dev Containers in VS Code
